# Why is a Python import implicitly executing parent modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

As the [Python documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages), a module import (as well as imports from a module) is always executing possible parent modules. For example with these files that constitute a regular package:

```
a_package/
  __init__.py
  a_submodule.py
```

An import from `a_submodule` in a completely different package, e.g.

```py
from a_package.a_submodule import an_object
```

would first execute `a_package/__init__.py` before executing `a_package/a_submodule.py` and eventually binding `an_object` into the namespace where the import is stated.

I'm wondering what the design rationale or technical necessity behind this is. In particular because it seems counter-intuitive to me as the usual package regime is an ordered graph where the parent modules are depending on contents from their subpackages, not vice versa. And as a matter of fact, if that import statement example was evaluated in `a_package/__init__.py`, it wouldn't trigger an execution of itself. Of course, because that'd be a cyclic dependency, yet it shows that submodules are not depending on their parent modules.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons.  The most important from a capability perspective is that a package can use mechanisms like `__path__` to help **find** its submodules, and that obviously won’t work if it weren’t configured before proceeding with the submodule import.  Another is a convenience: if a package needs **initialization** before its modules can be used, it can be put into `__init__.py` rather than having every module need `from . import startup`.

Moreover, at what other **time** should the package be initialized?  It doesn’t make sense to wait until *all* submodules are imported, since that might never happen; while it could be “after the first import of a submodule finishes”, that would still be before the import of other submodules and would be inconsistent and arbitrary.  In particular, no module could use the contents of its parent `__init__.py` in case it was the first among its siblings to be imported.

As for the cyclic dependency, Python has always supported those (at least for absolute imports): importing a module already being imported simply produces a **reference** to the module object (in its partially formed state).  The behavior of `from . import foo` (which is, as an aside, usually a bad idea as part of executing `__init__.py`) is no exception; as the “extra import” is just into `sys.modules` anyway, it has no effect at all.